# Изменяемые представления Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть представление

```
create view fname_five_view as
select employees.fname, employees.wagerate from employees, job_history
where job_history.numdepartment = 5 and job_history.num = employees.num
```

Нужно обновить ставку где < 0.5

```
update fname_five_view 
set wagerate = 0.5 
where wagerate < 0.5
```

Выдает ошибку:

> ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved
>   table

Comment: в представьление вроде должен быть уникальный ключ от таблицы `employees`

Comment: primary key ???

Comment: Да, primary key

Comment: Это не работает,

Comment: select employees.fname, employees.wagerate, employees.num

Answer (score 5):

В случае, если в представлении используется JOIN, то в таком представлении накладываются [очень жесткие ограничения](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#i1006232) на колонки, которые можно менять. Менять можно только колонки в так называемых *key preserved* таблицах. Чтобы таблица в представлении считалась *key preserved*, её первичный ключ должен потенциально оставаться таким же уникальным и в итоговой выборке, выполняемой представлением. А это возможно только в случае, если любые поля таблицы, участвующие в соединении (участвующие в on или where) ссылаются на первичные ключи других таблиц.

Судя по всему, в вашей ситуации все наоборот. Поле num в employees скорее всего первичный ключ, но в таблице, участвующей в соединении с ней job_history, поле num первичным ключом не является. Таким образом, *потенциально* один и тот же num таблицы employees может быть в нескольких записях выборки, образовавшихся за счет существования в таблице job_history нескольких записей с данным num. В такой ситуации только таблица job_history является *key preserved* и только ее поля, если бы они были в выборке, можно было бы менять.

Очевидно, что вы сделали JOIN только ради того, чтобы отфильтровать записи таблицы employees по факту наличия некоторых записей во второй таблице. Но не учли того факта, что в результате записи могут быть размножены. Самым простым решением было бы переписать запрос в view в виде:

```
create view fname_five_view as
  select employees.fname, employees.wagerate
    from employees 
   where num in(select num from job_history where numdepartment = 5);
```

В таком случае в запросе нет join и таблица employees заведомо является *key preserved* и ее поля могут быть обновлены.