# Как с UPDATE обновить колонку из JOIN двух таблиц (ошибка: ORA-00971)?

Tags: sql, oracle

Делаю `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Table1 T
JOIN Table2 A 
ON T.Account = A.Account AND T.Code_Currency = A.CODE_CURRENCY
SET A.BALANCE1 = 45010
WHERE T.PRODUCTID = 25;
```

Но выдает такую ошибку:

> ORA-00971: missing SET Keyword

Почему, как можно исправить?

Comment: Наверное, потому, что Oracle ни разу не MySQL. И в качестве источника данных для обновления (DML_table_expression_clause) у него может быть таблица, вьюв, подзапрос, коллекция... но никаких JOIN. так что используйте иные средства отбора записей - например, WHERE EXISTS или обновляемый подзапрос. См. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/UPDATE.html#GUID-027A462D-379D-4E35-8611-410F3AC8FDA5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если действительно нужно соединение таблиц в `UPDATE`, то можно с представлением:

```
create table t1 (account, productid, code_currency, 
    constraint uqt1 unique (account, code_currency)
    ) as select 2, 25, 1 from dual
/
create table t2 (account, code_currency, balance1) as
    select 2, 1, 0 from dual
/

update (
    select t.productid, a.balance1  
    from t1 t
    join t2 a on a.account=t.account and a.code_currency=t.code_currency)
set balance1 = 45010
where productid = 25
/ 

1 row updated.
```

В зависимости от ограничений, определённых на таблицах, возможно будет получена ошибка:

> ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Прична этой ошибки уже не раз обсуждалась, например, в темах [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/727606) и [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1038947).

Без соединение таблиц и независимо от ограничений, так будет работать:

```
alter table t1 drop constraint uqt1
/
update t2 a
set balance1 = 45010
where exists (
    select 1 from t1 t
    where productid = 25
    and a.account=t.account and a.code_currency=t.code_currency)
/ 

1 row updated.
```